# How can I save additional data during GitHub oAuth login with an ASP.NET Blazor Server web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've been trying to figure this out for about 5 days now and have tried so many things but nothing has worked.
** My goal is to authenticate a user with their GitHub account and save additional information such as their github account URL, profile picture, username, etc.

This is the api call in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGitHub(options => 
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["GitHub:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GitHub:ClientSecret"];
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-github");
            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
            options.TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";
            options.UsePkce = true;
            options.Scope.Add("repo");
            options.Scope.Add("user:email");
            options.Scope.Add("repo:status");
            options.Scope.Add("repo_deployment");
            options.Scope.Add("public_repo");
            options.Scope.Add("repo:invite");
            options.Scope.Add("admin:org");
            options.Scope.Add("notifications");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:url", "html_url");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:avatar", "avatar_url");

            //Scope for accessing API
            options.Scope.Add("identityApi");

            // Scope for custom user claim
            options.Scope.Add("appUser_claim");

            // map custom user claim 
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("appUser_claim", "appUser_claim");
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
            {
                List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

                tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                {
                    Name = "TicketCreated",
                    Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                });

                ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            options.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingGitHubTicket()
            };
```

Below this in Startup.cs I have this OnCreatingGitHubTicket() method. In this method I can actually see the data I want. The console.write shows the proper name, email and url of the person being logged in. I just have no idea of how I can save this data.

```
 private static Func<OAuthCreatingTicketContext, Task> OnCreatingGitHubTicket()
    {
        return async context =>
        {
            var fullName = context.Identity.FindFirst("urn:github:name").Value;
            var email = context.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
            var githuburl = context.Identity.FindFirst("urn:github:url").Value;


           // Here I can see the data
            Console.WriteLine(fullName + ", " + email + ", " + githuburl);

            await Task.FromResult(true);
        };
    }
```

Here I am setting the default identity to my custom UserModel in the Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserModel>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
             .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserModel>, MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

This is my UserModel class which contains the additional information I would like to gather during the login process:

```
public class UserModel : IdentityUser
{
    public UserModel() { }

    //[Key]

    [PersonalData]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string GitHubUrl { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

}

//public class ApplicationIdentityUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
//{
//    public virtual UserModel User { get; set; }
//    public virtual UserModel Role { get; set; }
//}
```

If you want me to post more code or give more information please ask. If you want to see the full repository it's on github here: https://github.com/kysu1313/BlazinAsp

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an object of a class with those information as properties? make it a global variable?

Comment: Hmm that's not a bad idea. I was hoping there was a way I could store the info directly in the AspNetUsers database table. But I might give this a try.